# rospy service question, how to specify service type

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to understand the tutorial here for rospy and services:
http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(python)
When the code does:

```
s = rospy.Service('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
```

I dont see how AddTwoInts is specified in the example code. I have a vague understanding that it should be an object storing all the data from AddTwoInts.srv, i dont know if thats correct?

But in python, how do I actually load the contents of AddTwoInts.srv into the object AddTwoInts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58087/rospy-service-question,-how-to-specify-service-type/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct that AddTwoInts is an object. You imported it with the `from beginner_tutorials.srv import *` command.

*Please note that the following explanation applies to rosbuild.* I haven't tried catkin just yet, and things are different there.

Anyway, in rosbuild, the generation of the python module happens when you run the command `rosmake`. There's a macro you put in the CMakeLists.txt file, `rosbuild_gensrv()` that does it for you.  This is why you still have to occasionally run `rosmake` even if you're using python.

(If I understand correctly, the same thing is happening in catkin, just without macros and using python or built in cmake macros instead. But like I said, I haven't actually tried it...)

If you'd like to look at the generated code, it should be in `beginner_tutorials/src/beginner_tutorials/srv/_AddTwoInts.py`

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0